# Unlock by administrator in C# ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When a user fails the login 3 times, they are blocked for 5 minutes. But I need the admin to be able to unlock the user. How can I do that?

I made shouldLockout: true

Login:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
```

IdentityConfig:

```
manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 3;
```

Comment: Call [this method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.setlockoutenabledasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_UserManager_1_SetLockoutEnabledAsync__0_System_Boolean_) from the admin side maybe?

Comment: You might try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.setlockoutenddateasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1 instead, coz I think `SetLockoutEnabledAsync()` just enables/disables account lockout feature for a specific user account. It looks like you can set the end date to the past with `SetLockoutEndDateAsync()` to immediately unlock the user.